# Unable to get sequelize findbyPk to return a single value to my React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

Novice here with what I'm sure will prove to be a silly question. I've tried to resolve myself without luck. In Postman the data returned to "localhost:8000/playlists/1" is correct, but I'm unable to repeat this success through the API call from my REact app at:3000. When I console.log out the data I'm getting all Playlists objects, not the single playlist as expected.

Below are my server routes and the call from React.

**PlaylistComponent in React**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";


const SeededPlaylist = () => {
  const [playlist, setPlaylistData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
            '/:playlistId'
        );
        setPlaylistData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
}, []);

console.log(playlist);

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
       {playlist.map(playlist => (
             <div key={playlist.id}>
            {playlist.title}
            </div>

            ))}



    </div>
  );
}
  export default SeededPlaylist
```

**Playlist Routes from Node**

```
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const playlists = await req.context.models.Playlist.findAll({
   include: [{
     model: req.context.models.Song,
     attributes: ['track_name', 'artist_name', 'track_duration'],
     through: { attributes: [] }
   }],
  });

  return res.send(playlists);
});

router.get('/:playlistId', async (req, res) => {
  const playlist = await req.context.models.Playlist.findByPk(req.params.playlistId, {
    include: [{
      model: req.context.models.Song,
      attributes: ['track_name', 'artist_name', 'track_duration'],
      through: { attributes: [], }
    }],
  });

  return res.send(playlist);
});

export default router;
```

**Relevant Routers in server.js**

```
app.use('/playlists', routes.playlist);
app.use('/:playlistId', routes.playlist);
app.use('/songs', routes.song);
app.use('/', routes.spotify);
```

EDIT: I'm 90% sure I'm not getting a specific ID correctly and need to save my URL or the specific ID to my axios request. Not sure how to do that yet, but I'll keep looking.

EDIT 2:
If anyone else ends up here, the issue was as guessed. I was not correctly targeting the URL in the API call. I ended up grabbing the ID from the URL itself with useParams and then using that was a template literal in the get request.

```
const { id } = useParams();

  //Fetch Playlist data from API with Axios
  useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const songUri = [];
        const response = await axios(`http://localhost:8000/playlists/${id}`
        );
        setPlaylistData(response.data);
        setSongs(response.data.songs);
        for (const spotify_uri of Object.keys(response.data)){
          console.log(spotify_uri, response.data[spotify_uri]);
        }
      }
      //Second Array prevents activation on component update
        fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Relevant Routers in server.js**

```
app.use('/playlists', routes.playlist);
// app.use('/:playlistId', routes.playlist); This is no need, we must remove this line
app.use('/songs', routes.song);
app.use('/', routes.spotify);
```